# Cancel Google Analytics Loading bar

Tags: google-analytics, plugin

Is there any way to cancel this loading bar?If any chrome plugin or any option within Google analytics available.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the back button?

Comment: Are you trying to cancel the load operation? or remove the display of the loading bar?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to direct way to specifically close or cancel the "loading" operation. Either you reload the page (which doesn't mean you go through the "loading" bar again), or you navigate elsewhere (as alluded to by @Stephen).

Comment: If you want to hide the loading operation you can copy and paste the following into the console: document.querySelector("#ID-reportLoading > div > div.ID-loadingProgressBarScreen._GAIK > div").style.display= "none";